# Am I using Rsync properly?

Tags: mac, external-hard-drive, sync, rsync

This is my desired outcome:

[image]

Where I would like such an outcome across ALL sub-directories and files, in syncing all the contents of parent directory Work from my computer's desktop to an older version of directory Work on my external HD, would the below be the appropriate `rsync` command? I have just started using `rsync`! Thank you!

Note I'm starting at the root directory `Macintosh HD` where you can see `Applications`, `Library`, `Network`, `System`, `Volumes` etc. The external hard drive already has a Work directory that I'm syncing with what's on my desktop, since the one on external HD is much older.

```
rsync -a Users/<myname>/Desktop/Work/ /Volumes/WD\ Passport/<myname>/Work/
```

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I'm wrong... I did some testing. The command as I originally wrote it did NOT achieve the desired outcome in row 5. If destination file had a NEWER timestamp, this would still replace that one with the source file of the same name. Instead, I needed an `--update` flag:

```
rsync -a --update Users/<myname>/Desktop/Work/ /Volumes/WD\ Passport/<myname>/Work/
```

I think I read somewhere that some people used `--ignore-existing` which also isn't correct. That basically doesn't move a file from source to destination if it already exists by name on destination. So having that flag would violate row 4's requirement

Not sure if this is required, but I also needed to be in my root directory for this to work.

ALSO, if same file is sorted under different sub directories, this may result in duplication. E.g.,

Destination has Tester/FileA
Source moved it into a new subdirectory Tester/NewDir/FileA

What will happen is that Destination will receive a copy of NewDir/FileA, and now in Destination, FileA will exist in two places, in NewDir/FileA (most recently sync'd version) and in Tester/FileA.

This is more standard behavior that I'm fine with

Comment: Hi, in the future try to update your original question with additional information. Posting it as an answer can lead to it getting lost (for example, other answers are provided and push this down). Its also easier for people who want to provide an answer to have all the information in one block.

Comment: this is an answer though... it's just an asnwer with additional notes to it